# Reading node based on condition from Multi-Level xml in Java

Tags: java

I am working with the below XML structure and reading the `GUID` value from the `Address` node where `UsageCode` value is set as "STANDARD". The code was working fine but now `AddressUsage` segment is redefined as optional by the source system and thus `UsageCode` is not returned for all `Address` nodes in the XML.

```
<BusinessPartner>
   <ID>2494271</ID>
   <Address>
      <GUID>000d8a5c-8bc5-1eda-b8cc-53078a383c3f</GUID>
      <ValidityPeriod>
         <StartDate>2020-08-06</StartDate>
         <EndDate>9999-12-31</EndDate>
      </ValidityPeriod>
   </Address>
   <Address>
      <GUID>000d8a5c-8bc5-1eda-b8cc-53078a384c5f</GUID>
      <ValidityPeriod>
         <StartDate>2020-08-06</StartDate>
         <EndDate>9999-12-31</EndDate>
      </ValidityPeriod>
      <AddressUsage>
         <UsageCode>STANDARD</UsageCode>
      </AddressUsage>
   </Address>
</BusinessPartner>
```

The XML above can have multiple `Address` segments, and `AddressUsage` node is optional.
Due to missing `AddressUsage` node this code is now returning wrong `GUID` (from the first `Address` node).

Any suggestion how to fix this?

```
// Get Document Builder
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

// Build Document
Document document = builder.parse(new File("BPData2.xml"));

// Normalize the XML Structure;
document.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList AddList = document.getElementsByTagName("AddressUsage");
for (int i = 0; i < AddList.getLength(); i++) {
    NodeList AddChildList = AddList.item(i).getChildNodes();
    for (int j = 0; j < AddChildList.getLength(); j++) {
        Node UsageChildNode = AddChildList.item(j);
        if ("UsageCode".equals(UsageChildNode.getNodeName()) && 
            "STANDARD".equals(AddChildList.item(j).getTextContent())) {
            NodeList AddUUID = document.getElementsByTagName("GUID");
            System.out.println(AddUUID.item(i).getTextContent());
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UsageCode` is the tag you are interested in, so get those elements, rather than `AddressUsage`. For each element, check that its text content is "STANDARD" and if it is, get the grandparent node – which is the `Address` element. Then iterate through the children of `Address` until you find `GUID`. Get the text content of `GUID` and you're done.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XmlPars2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(new File("BPData2.xml"));
            document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList usages = document.getElementsByTagName("UsageCode");
            int count = usages.getLength();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                Node n = usages.item(i);
                if ("STANDARD".equals(n.getTextContent())) {
                    Node parent = n.getParentNode();
                    Node grandparent = parent.getParentNode();
                    NodeList children = grandparent.getChildNodes();
                    int count2 = children.getLength();
                    for (int j = 0; j < count2; j++) {
                        Node target = children.item(j);
                        if ("GUID".equals(target.getNodeName())) {
                            System.out.println(target.getTextContent());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException | ParserConfigurationException | SAXException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the above code is based on the sample XML in your question.

Comment: Thanks Abra. I am grateful for your valuable help. I didn't knew it is possible to navigate using the bottom-up approach to get the node value.